# Move an array of pictureboxes constantly C#

Tags: c#

```
    public int level = 1;
    public PictureBox[] invaders;

    public void spawn(int level)
    {
        int f = 0;

        invaders = new PictureBox[100];
        PictureBox invader = new PictureBox();
        Bitmap img = (WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.SpaceInvader);
        for (int n = 32; n < (4 + level)*32; n=n+32)
        {
            for (int i = 90; i < 400; i = i + 37)
            {
                invaders[f] = new PictureBox();
                invaders[f].Location = new Point(i, n);
                invaders[f].Size = new Size(20, 15);
                invaders[f].Image = img;
                invaders[f].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                invaders[f].BackColor = Color.Transparent;

                this.Controls.Add(invaders[f]);

                f++;
            }
        }
        timer2.Interval = 10;
        timer2.Start();
    }
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < invaders.Length; i++)
        {
            invaders[i].Location = new Point(invaders[i].Location.X + 1, invaders[i].Location.Y);
        }
    }
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SpaceInvaders.exe

All the pictures move across once and then the error occurs. Any solutions?

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: invaders[i].Location = new Point(invaders[i].Location.X + 1, invaders[i].Location.Y);

Comment: Not all places in the invaders array are filled. Why do you not use a List instead of an array?

Comment: You are failing to initialize one of the 100 picture boxes in your array. It is hard to say which at a glance, I can't easily make sense of your `spawn` logic. Your end conditions and steps in the nested loops are quite confusing.

Comment: I switched the array to a list and everything is now moving. But I still have a problem, everything has become extremely slow. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using GDI Or DirectX to draw an image on the surface of a control.
this will be extremely fast. i believe you have not used directx before so i would suggest picking up some simple examples to render image using directx. its quite simple really.

for GDI you can start with this simple example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-render-images-with-gdi